# Can I set a zero fee to transaction if there is less transaction volume than space in the blocks?

Tags: transaction-fees

I'd like to set a zero fee to transaction when block is spacious.

Is it acceptable and can be confirmed by network, miner on BTC, BCH, BTG ... these chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* set a zero fee in BTC, it is regarded as a dust. The transaction *can* confirm in the case you have asked about but, if it *will* confirm is dependant upon the transaction broadcast by the individual nodes, the node may not accept a transaction with fees below a particular level, particularly if that nodes mempool is rather full, and it depends on *if* miners will include the transaction in a block.

Even if in the past there have been zero fee transactions included in blocks, I would not risk it.